# Find the real and imaginary parts of function

Tags: complex-numbers

I need to find the real and imaginary parts of
$$2^{z^{2}}$$

What I've done:

$$z = (x + iy)$$ so
$$2^{z^2} = 2 ^{{(x + iy)}^2}= 2^{x^2+2xyi-y^2}$$

And I don't know how to solve this on. Can anyone help me?

Comment: $(2^z)^2$ is not $2^{(z^2)}$.

Comment: As @GerryMyerson mentioned, it should be $2^{2z}$, but the computation is very similar. You need to obtain an expression of the form $2^{a+bi}=2^a*2^ib$, writing $2=e^{\ln 2}$ gives $$ 2^{a+bi} = 2^a * e^{ib \ln 2} = 2^a * (\cos(\ln 2* b) + i\sin (\ln 2 *b))$$

Comment: Yes, my bad... I tryed 2^(z^2) but that looked bad and I made this mistake :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: the question was modified, so I modify my answer, letting the old answer below, so it is possible to see the difference between the two problems.

As you stated:
$$2^{z^2} = 2^{x^2-y^2+2xyi} = 2^{x^2}2^{-y^2}2^{2xyi} = 2^{x^2}2^{-y^2}4^{xyi} \ .$$
Now you can transform the complex exponential $4^{xyi}$ into a complex exponential with basis $e$ and use logarithm properties:
$$4^{xyi} = e^{\log 4^{xy i}} = e^{i xy \log 4} \ .$$
Now $\log 4 $ is just a number and we can write $e^{ixy \log 4}$ in trigonometric form:
$$e^{ixy \log 4} = \cos(xy\log 4) + i \sin(xy \log 4).$$
Putting all together, we have:
$$2^{z^2} = 2^{x^2}2^{-y^2}\cos(xy\log 4) + i \, 2^{x^2}2^{-y^2}\sin(xy \log 4) \ .$$
So, the real part is $2^{x^2}2^{-y^2}\cos(xy\log 4)$ and the imaginary part is $i \, 2^{x^2}2^{-y^2}\sin(xy \log 4)$.

Note that here $\log$ refers to the natural logarithm.

OLD ANSWER:
$$(2^{z})^2=(2^2)^z = 4^z = 4^{x+iy}=4^x4^{iy} \ .$$
Now you can transform the complex exponential $4^{iy}$ into a complex exponential with basis $e$ and use logarithm properties:
$$4^{iy}=e^{\log 4^{iy}} = e^{iy \log 4} \ .$$
Now $\log 4 $ is just a number and we can write $e^{iy \log 4}$ in trigonometric form:
$$e^{iy \log 4} = \cos(y\log 4) + i \sin(y \log 4).$$
Putting all together, we have:
$$(2^{z})^2 = 4^x\cos(y\log 4) + i \, 4^x\sin(y \log 4) \ .$$
So, the real part is $4^x\cos(y\log 4)$ and the imaginary part is $i \, 4^x\sin(y \log 4)$.

Note that here $\log$ refers to the natural logarithm.

Comment: Sorry, but there was a mistake in my question..(

Comment: @Mzia thanks, I edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

$$2^{z^2} = 2 ^{{(x + iy)}^2}= 2^{x^2+2xyi-y^2} = 2^{x^2-y^2}*4^{xyi}= 2^{x^2-y^2}*e^{ixy\ln(4)} =  2^{x^2-y^2}*(\cos(xy\ln(4)) + i\sin(xy\ln(4)))$$

So the real part is $$2^{x^2-y^2}*\cos(xy\ln(4))$$
and the imaginary part is $$2^{x^2-y^2}*\sin(xy\ln(4))$$

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).